# strace init process (PID 1) in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, strace

The strace [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) says:

> On Linux, exciting as it would be, tracing the init process is
>   forbidden.

I checked the same and it doesn't allow it:

```
$  strace -p 1
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
```

Why isn't it possible? Even the ptrace manpage says the same about tracing init process. Aren't these tools safe or just that the init process is deemed too special that no other processes (strace/ptrace) can signal it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143561/why-wont-strace-gdb-attach-to-a-process-even-though-im-root

Comment: that link doesn't talk about init process. I am aware if the process is being run with gdb/valgrind, one can't strace it. But this is a different case.

Comment: Just a semi-educated guess, but it's quite possible that there is something about the `init` process that makes it not quite a true process because of the way it is spawned (e.g. it doesn't have a parent process, and probably other bits of the process metadata are odd for similar reasons), which means `strace` would have to have a bunch of special-case treatment of things in order to work with `init`, and to date, nobody has seen enough value in tracing `init` to implement the code.

Comment: @twalberg: I have no purpose to strace init, just curious why it can't be traced. I checked the `strace` working. To trace a process it becomes the parent of that process, and can send signals to it. Probably messing with `init` in such a way isn't allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo strace -p 1` works for me ( you need root privileges for `strace` )
There was [work](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/3/23/232) to allow debugging of init. In 2.4.37 you can't [attach](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=2.4.37#L59) to `init`, but in some kernel this condition was removed - I've found 3.8 [kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=3.8#L295)

Edit: on my Kubuntu 15.10 there is no `On Linux, exciting as it would be, tracing the init process is forbidden.` in `strace` man. Updated man?

Comment: A little clarification: `strace` doesn't need root privileges in general, but it needs them to trace processes of other users.